# spring data cassandra reactive - custom delete method

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am currently trying to specify a delete method in my ReactiveCrudRepository. There ar predefined delete methods which work as expected. But my primary key is named msisdn and not id so i need to define a custom method to delete entries by this key.

This is my approach. notice the Mono return type. it is the same as used by the `ReactiveCrudRepository` from spring

```
public interface RegistrationRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<RegistrationEntity, String> {

    Mono<RegistrationEntity> findByMsisdn(String msisdn);

    Mono<Void> deleteByMsisdn(String msisdn);
}
```

I wrote a simple test where test data is persistet in a inmemory cassandra instance and afterwards i try to delete the entry. But i get following exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.Void!

    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.DtoInstantiatingConverter.<init>(DtoInstantiatingConverter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.ReactiveCassandraQueryExecution$ResultProcessingConverter.convert(ReactiveCassandraQueryExecution.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.ReactiveCassandraQueryExecution$ResultProcessingExecution.execute(ReactiveCassandraQueryExecution.java:196)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.AbstractReactiveCassandraQuery.executeNow(AbstractReactiveCassandraQuery.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.AbstractReactiveCassandraQuery.execute(AbstractReactiveCassandraQuery.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.deleteByMsisdn(Unknown Source)
    at ch.sbb.kat.fc.service.CassandraRepositoryTest.deleteTest(CassandraRepositoryTest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
```

Replacing the returntype with Mono does not work. It just returns the object without deleting it.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use a `MapId` instead of `String`
:

```
public interface RegistrationRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<RegistrationEntity, MapId> {

}
```